# AWS IAM user can access EKS cluster via kubectl, but not on EKS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

This is a follow up question to my post [AWS IAM user that belongs to an IAM group cannot assume IAM role that the IAM group was allowed to assume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405842/aws-iam-user-that-belongs-to-an-iam-group-cannot-assume-iam-role-that-the-iam-gr), which has an answer.

So now my `cijenkins` user can issue `kubectl` commands on the EKS cluster. However, if I log into AWS console and access the EKS cluster there, I see. Why?

[image]

Comment: The role policy for that user doesn't include `eks:ListClusters`

Comment: That user is a member of a group that can assume a role that has this policy `{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow","Action": ["eks:*"Resource": "*"}]}`

Comment: If your logged in as that user, you'll still need to assume the role in the UI. "switch role" from the dropdown in the top right.

Comment: @jordanm wow, that was it. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it if you wish. thanks!